# Order by annotation and use values() without returning annotation in Django's ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to run the following queries:

```
labels = AssetLabel.objects.filter(organization=request.organization).annotate(num_assets=Count('asset'))
labels = list(labels.order_by('-num_assets')[:20].values('id', 'name'))
```

This gives me an error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'num_assets' into field. Choices are: asset, id, name, organization
```

If I add `num_assets` to `.values()`, then I don't get an error. However, I don't want `num_assets` to be returned. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

check the function `extra`, it has a parameter called `order_by` so you can use this function to order given `QuerySet`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

I guess it might be something like this:

```
labels = AssetLabel.objects. \
    filter(organization=request.organization). \
    extra(
        select={'num_assets': "Count('asset')"},
        order_by=['num_assets']
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `annotate` before `values`, the example from [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses):

> You should also note that average_rating has been explicitly included in the list of values to be returned. This is required because of the ordering of the values() and annotate() clause.

ValuesQuerySet will always contain the annotate field, iter it to remove the field,

```
values = labels.order_by('-num_assets')[:20].values('id', 'name')
for value in values:
    value.pop('num_assets')
```